# WP Avada Form How to Track Form Submission

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, conversion-tracking

I have a WP website using Avada theme.

Before runing ads on google,

I want to be able to track form submission for Avada Form.

How am I suppose to do that?

(I have already inserted the GA code below)

```
    <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-3CWQGHB9KD"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-3CWQGHB9KD');
</script>
```

I have tried looked into the Avada Form's setting. I couldn't find anything useful there.

Answer (score 0):

Avada already has this built in. When you build the form, you need to make sure that:

1. Build the form
2. Scroll to the bottom under form options
3. Under Submission>Actions>Click in the field
4. Select save to databse.

Once users start submitting data to the form

1. Go to Avada>Forms
2. You will see the number of entries along with a link to view submissions.
3. Adding the save to database option is crucial to tracking form submissions.